# Erase custom error message in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I use a dialog jquery for insert some data in form,so my input field(for the dialog) is mandatory,I added a div in my dialog to display a text(Error) when I click for insert my data.
At this step all works perfectly,My problem is to find a way to erase the text message when i start typing on my field: I tried in this way with my codebut without any result:

```
$( "#MyDialog2" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 700,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "ADD": function() {
            if ($("#keyword_new_nameadd").val() == "") {
                $("#myDialogText").text("Name required");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#keyword_new_nameadd").bind('keydown keypress change', function() {
                    $("#myDialogText").text("");//Doesnt work for erasing at this step
                    //alert("Bingo");
                });
            }
            $("#add_keyword").click(); 
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $('#keyword_new_nameadd').val("");
        $("#myDialogText").text("");
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Did you check that the handler gets called? (do you get the "Bingo" alert when uncommented?) It seems to me that the handler is not getting `bind`ed at a good time. It gets bound only when you click ADD and the text box is already valid (and then the dialog gets closed right away). Try putting it in the `if`, right before `return false;`.

Comment: Yes thanks it was that you suggest me: I added it in the if ,before return false;